# How to root my Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900A) (kernel version: July 22, 2014)?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900A). I am aware of [towelroot](https://towelroot.com/), however it only works for "phones < jun 3 2014" for and my kernel version is dated July 22, 2014:

[image]

How to root it, if possible without tripping the KNOX counter?

[Kingo](http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/devices.htm) doesn't seem to support Samsung Galaxy S5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should search on xda developers on the forum for your specific device but i don't think you can root it without flag knox and break the warranty i have an S4 with knox too and  i couldn't find an way to root without flagging the knox counter

http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/#odin << here you can find the autoroot for your device and will flag knox just download it and follow the  steps you can easily find on xda developers on how to use odin

Comment: Here's a working solution for rooted Lollipop on S5 from AT&T, that I found in XDA, and summarized:  http://android.stackexchange.com/a/170154/122842