# How to root Samsung Galaxy S5 for AT&T with Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5, att

I have Samsung Galaxy S5 for AT&T with Android 5.0 Lollipop upgraded.

Is there any way to root this phone?

PS.
[How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)
This question is different.
I heard that rooting Lollipop is different from rooting previous Android version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an XDA instructions to root **Samsung S5 G900A (AT&T)**: 
https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s5/general/guide-merry-christmas-heres-t3516196

That's the only solution I found working!

1) Save these to the Samsung SD card:

- [SuperSU APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=457095661767138998)
- [Towelroot APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=457095661767139000)
- [Flashfire APK](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=817550096634747981)
- [pre-rooted OF3 firmware](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=673368273298933039)

2) Now on your Desktop PC, download this firmware:
[COMBINATION_ATT_FA44_G900AUCU4AOF1_ATT4AOF1.zip](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=745425885120704448)

3) Install the "COMBINATION" firmware using [Samsung Odin](https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Odin_mode) (you'll have to boot your device by pressing Volume Down + Home + Power ON)
**This will wipe ALL data** on the device! Backup your stuff before proceeding.

4) After this new firmware installed and loaded, open Android file manager, go to the SD card, and install those APKs: Flashfire, SuperSU, and TowelRoot.

5) Connect to the internet (Wifi), and then go into "Settings > Date and Time" and tick the "Automatic date and time" box. This is mandatory for TowelRoot to work.

6) Run TowelRoot app -> "make it ra1n". Now you'll have the root binaries installed.

7) Run SuperSU app -> "new user" -> update SU binaries -> reboot.

8) Run FlashFire app -> grant it root access -> flash ZIP -> choose the OF3 firmware from SD -> set options to Mount /system read/write -> Hit "flash".

You're done! Enjoy Samsung S5 with Lollipop unlocked!

Answer (score 0):

[Root Samsung Galaxy S5](http://androidxda.net/root-galaxy-s5-sm-g900h-on-android-5-0-lollipop-build-xxu1boa7-using-cf-auto-root-tool/)
Although the given link is for the build xxu1b0a7, it worked for my mobile with build xxu1b0c3. So you can give it a try.

But I recommend you to not root your mobile, as the samsung will be releasing the 5.1.1 update and it will be of minimal bloatware.